# How can I check if IP is a Tor exit node?

Tags: security, tor

I have someone attacking my site and it would seem some of the IPs are Tor exit nodes.

Is there somewhere I can input an IP and definitively see if it's registered as a Tor exit node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Tor Project has a tool to do this at:

https://exonerator.torproject.org/

For automated lookups, they also provide a DNSBL-based lookup; information on that is available at:

https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en

Comment: How can I setup an API like what exonerator has? the TorDNSEL docs aren't super clear to me

Comment: @Antoine You don't have to set up an API, it's already provided.

Comment: How can I use it like the exonerator though, where I plug in an IP and receive word back on whether it's an exit node? This API: `[service port].[reversed service
    address].ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org` isn't super clear to me, what's a reversed service address in this instance?

Comment: @Antoine Read the web page for DNSEL, under "What do the received answers mean?".

Comment: @Antoine you can use https://github.com/assafmo/IsTorExit

Answer (score 3):

I actually implemented the solution @duskwuff suggested.
Check it out at - https://github.com/assafmo/IsTorExit

CLI:

```
npm install -g istorexit
istorexit [ip...]
```

NodeJs:

```
const IsTorExit = require("istorexit");
IsTorExit("104.200.20.46").then(console.log); // true
IsTorExit("1.1.1.1").then(console.log); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.ipqualityscore.com/tor-ip-address-check/lookup

On this link you can check if IP is an tor exit node.

Answer (score 2):

Download the list of all exit node IPs from https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist and check whether the IP is in the list.

Alternatively, you can do a DNS query to check a single IP address. Make a DNS A query to `[reverse ip address].dnsel.torproject.org`. If it returns `127.0.0.2`, then the IP is a Tor exit IP address. For example, to check the `12.34.56.78` address, you can run this console command:

```bash
nslookup 78.56.34.12.dnsel.torproject.org
```

If it returns `Address: 127.0.0.2`, then it's a Tor IP.

Comment: The list does not have ipv6 and is only about 1.3k items, other sources are showing 10k exit nodes...?

Comment: I was thinking the same. Did you come to a conclusion or know more details in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl solution based on https://github.com/assafmo/IsTorExit

```perl
my @ips = ('1.1.1.1','1.2.1.1','1.3.1.1','1.4.1.1','1.5.1.1','104.200.20.46');
foreach (@ips)
{
    print("IP: $_\n");

    # Build the command by reversing the IP address (ie. 1.5.1.1 to 1.1.5.1)
    # Checking 1.5.1.1 via 1.1.5.1.dnsel.torproject.org
    # (https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en - How can I query the public TorDNSEL service?)
    # Lookup from a linux system using dig (+short to have a light answer)
    my $cmd = "dig +short ".join(".", reverse split(/\./, $_)).".dnsel.torproject.org";
    my $res = `$cmd`;
    $res =~ s/^\s^|\s+$//g;
    print(" Command: [$cmd] ; Result: [$res]\n");

    # A records inside net 127/8, except 127.0.0.1, are reserved for future use
    # and should be interpreted by clients as indicating an exit node
    # (https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en - What do the received answers mean?)
    my $is_tor = 0;
    $is_tor = 1 if ($res =~ /^127\.0\.0\./ && $res ne "127.0.0.1");
    print(" Is Tor? [$is_tor]\n");
}
```