# Restrict access to server for TOR and VPN users

Tags: vpn, blocking, ip-blocking, tor

Is this possible to restrict access to all users, who try to connect to my web server using TOR or VPN? I'd like to geoblock some users and also want to avoid them accessing my website even if they are using anonymization tools.

Comment: The TOR network provides a ready made list of current TOR exit nodes here https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist which should make it relatively to incorporate those in a firewall - see for example https://serverfault.com/a/1106655/984089

Comment: And for example  https://serverfault.com/q/874327/984089